# Issue with ExecuteNonQuery

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

My code times out on the ExecuteNonQuery line below.  I don't know why. I've increased the timeout to 900 and it still times out.

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(localConnection))

        {
            var command = String.Format(@"UPDATE dbo.Documents SET DocFile = {0} WHERE ID = '{1}'", @"BulkColumn from Openrowset(Bulk 'C:\Work\Document.docx', Single_Blob) AS DocFile", projID);
            using (var sqlWrite = new SqlCommand(command, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                sqlWrite.Parameters.Add("@File", SqlDbType.VarBinary, file.Length).Value = file;
                sqlWrite.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

Comment: How long does it take when you run this query through SSMS?

Comment: Why are you passing in a parameter `@File` then never using it?

Comment: I suspect its because your query runs slowly

Comment: You should use parameterised queries also, as the current code is susceptible to SQL Injection Attack.

Comment: Why is your `ID` column textual? Why are you storing the whole document in the row?

Comment: how big is the file that is being processed here?

Comment: Remove The Timeout or expand its limit and let it run, give it ten minutes or so, see if it carries out the task, its like the others have mentioned.. it all depends on the size of the file its reading.

Comment: I think there's something wrong with OPENROWSET command. How much is the size of Document.docx file? and Does the current user have access permissions on it?

Comment: another thought: is `C:\Work\Document.docx` relative to the *server* ? or relative to the *client* ? (hint: the path needs to be relative to the server)

Comment: @IvanG -  This query runs immediately in SSMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a bulk activity, which I imagine is updating many many rows, it's probably legitimately taking that long.  Try setting the timeout to `0` for "No timeout" and see if it will complete.

- [SqlConnection.ConnectionTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout.aspx)

Comment: It has a `WHERE` clause on `id` so presumably only updates at most one row.

Comment: @MartinSmith a `WHERE` clause, even to a single row, doesn't necessarily mean it isn't doing a ton of work. But indeed, the "many many rows" is probably misleading

Comment: @MartinSmith, are you assuming that the textual `ID` column is a Primary or Candidate Key?

Comment: @Jodrell - Yes. Generally speaking a column called `ID` would be the PK but who knows without the DDL? We also don't know that it is textual. they have single quotes around it but these may be unnecessary and it may be numeric. They should be parameterising that anyway.

Comment: @MartinSmith, generally speaking, I'd compare it to a integer value in my `Where` clause.

Comment: @MartinSmith What is the size of the file it's loading as well?  If you're trying to load a 1GB file into the DB it's going to take some time...